# Why the closures don't get correct outer values with async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

See the following nodejs code with [async](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
var async = require('async');

function inc(n, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        cb(null, n+1);
    },1000);
};

var calls = [];

for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    calls.push(function(cb){
        inc(i, cb);
    });
}

async.parallel(calls, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

It prints:

```
[4, 4, 4]
```

I don't understand why the result isn't `[1, 2, 3]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because every **call** in `calls` array references the same `i` variable, think this code:

```
function fn() {
    var i = 1;
    setTimeout(function() { alert(i); }, 500);
    i++;
    i++;
}
fn();
```

This, certainly, would output **3** instead of **1**, this is the same issue of your code, the variable `i` changed before the **call** executes;

To avoid this problem, wrap **for** loop with a **Immediately Invoked Function Expression** to create a new scope to store the value of `i`

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        calls.push(function(cb) { inc(i, cb); });
    }(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    calls.push(function(cb){
        inc(i, cb);
    });
}
```

The functions are getting executed after the end of the `for` loop; at the time, `i` equals `3`.

You should use another closure here. For example:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    calls.push(function (i) {
        return function (cb) {
            inc(i, cb);
        }
    }(i));
}
```