# Javascript function doesn't receive an argument correctly

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript closures and variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314175/javascript-closures-and-variable-scope)
>   [Assign click handlers in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop)

I have this script:

```
var MyClass = {
    MyArray: new Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),

    MyFunc1: function() {
        var i = 0;
        for (i = MyClass.MyArray.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
            var cen = document.getElementById("cen_" + i); // It is an img element
                cen.src = "col.png";
                cen.className = "cen_act";
                cen.onclick = function() { MyClass.MyFunc1(i); };
            } else {
                cen.src = "no.png";
                cen.className = "cen";
                cen.onclick = null;
            }
        }
    },

    MyFunc2: function(id) {
        alert(id);
    }
}
```

My problem is that, at this line :`cen.onclick = function() { MyClass.MyFunc1(i); };` the argument sent to `MyFunc2` is always **-1**. The `MyFunc1` function should create four images, each one with an *onclick* event. When you click on each image, the MyFunc2 function should show the corresponding  *i* value. It looks like the *i* value is not "saved" for each event and image element created, but only its "pointer".

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closures and variable scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314175/javascript-closures-and-variable-scope) -- this kind of question has been asked a million times, but I understand that it is not easy to search for it if you don't know what the problem is. Also see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314175/javascript-closures-and-variable-scope#comment2281960_2314175).

Comment: If you agree to be removed, no problem by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal case and misunderstand of **closures**, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594897/why-the-closures-dont-get-correct-outer-values-with-async/10594943#10594943) and you may get some clue, the simply way to fix this problem is to wrap your **for** loop body with an **Immediate Invoked Function Expression**

```
MyFunc1: function() {
    var i = 0;
    for (i = MyClass.MyArray.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
        (function(i) {
            var cen = document.getElementById("cen_" + i); // An img element
                cen.src = "col.png";
                cen.className = "cen_act";
                cen.onclick = function() { MyClass.MyFunc2(i); };
            } else {
                cen.src = "no.png";
                cen.className = "cen";
                cen.onclick = null;
            }
        }(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote because this isn't wrong, but probably not the best solution to the problem due to the performance hit from constantly adding to the scope stack by executing an IIFE every iteration through the loop.

Comment: Sometimes, I forget that JavaScript is not C++, either PHP. Thanks to everyone. I will accept your answer, since it is the first one.

Answer (score 2):

You should be familiar with the concept of [JavaScript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) to understand why this happens. If you are, then you should remember that every instance of the

```
function() { MyClass.MyFunc1(i); };
```

function closure contains `i`'s value of `-1` (since it is the **final** value of this variable after the entire loop finishes executing.) To avoid this, you might either use `bind`:

```
cen.onclick = (function(i) { MyClass.MyFunc1(i); }).bind(null, i);
```

or use an explicitly created closure with the proper `i` value.

Answer (score 1):

You are capturing a variable that changes inside the loop, so you always get the last value of i.

You can easily fix that by creating a closure:

```
MyFunc1: function() {
    var i = 0;
    for (i = MyClass.MyArray.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
        (function(i) {

        var cen = document.getElementById("cen_" + i); // An img element
            cen.src = "col.png";
            cen.className = "cen_act";
            cen.onclick = function() { MyClass.MyFunc2(i); };
        } else {
            cen.src = "no.png";
            cen.className = "cen";
            cen.onclick = null;
        }
       })(i);
    }
},
```